# Swift Codable Decode Date format for *One* key

Tags: json, swift, date-formatting, codable

I have a JSON structure that looks like this:

```json
{
  "start_date": "2021-12-31",
  "created_at": "2021-12-30T23:36:25-06:00"
}
```

Both of the values (`start_date`, `created_at`) have a different date format, but need to be parsed on the same level as each other. My swift struct looks like:

```swift
struct ExampleDateFormatProblem: Codable {
  var startDate: Date
  var createdAt: Date

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case startDate = "start_date"
    case createdAt = "created_at"
  }
}
```

And is being decoded using

```swift
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.'SSS'Z'"

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)
decoder.decode // (basic decoding stuff here, just showing the date formatting)
```

This struct can decode perfectly fine without the `start_date` format, but when adding that back in it breaks due to it not being the same date format as the date format I've set the JSONDecoder to.

So here's my question, how do I define a date format to use for *one* property in a struct? In this example I need to say "start_date should be decoded using this format, and created_at using another". Is this even possible using Swift's Codable?

Comment: Have you considered either the [`.custom`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/datedecodingstrategy/custom) date decoding strategy, or overriding `init(from:)` for your struct?

Comment: surely this will helps  https://medium.com/@pxpgraphics/decoding-custom-types-with-decodable-in-swift-4-c730597da373

Comment: I really don't want to use a custom initializer because it adds so much overhead. The .custom date decoding strategy would apply to the *entire* JSON document. I already have a date format for the document, I just need to decode the one value using a new format.

Comment: @dahiya_boy Oh hmm, that actually gives me an idea. Maybe I can use property wrappers to define formats for specific values

Comment: @thecoolwinter FWIW, your current `dateDecodingStrategy` already applies to the entire JSON document. With a `.custom` strategy, you can check the decoder's `.codingPath` to check the last key in the path: if it's equal to `ExampleDateFormatProblem.CodingKeys.startDate`, you can use one format; if not, you can fall back to your existing `dateFormatter`

Comment: If you don’t want to custom decode the entire json then you could create your own date wrapper type which has a custom decoder init. You can then embed your decoding strategy into it without having to worry about the rest of the json. If you need then transform it to another type later.

Answer (score 2):

*heavy thanks to @Fogmeister and @dahiya_boy for the inspiration here*

You can define property wrappers that conform to Codable, so we can make a protocol to conform `Date` to codable using a format.

```swift
// MARK: - Property Wrappers

public protocol DateValueCodableStrategy {
    associatedtype RawValue: Codable

    static func decode(_ value: RawValue) throws -> Date
    static func encode(_ date: Date) -> RawValue
}

/// Uses a format to decode a date from Codable.
@propertyWrapper struct DateFormatted<T: DateValueCodableStrategy>: Codable {
    private let value: T.RawValue
    var wrappedValue: Date
    
    public init(wrappedValue: Date) {
            self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
            self.value = T.encode(wrappedValue)
        }
        
        public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            self.value = try T.RawValue(from: decoder)
            self.wrappedValue = try T.decode(value)
        }
        
        public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
            try value.encode(to: encoder)
        }
}

// MARK: - Date Formats

struct DayDateStrategy: DateValueCodableStrategy {
    private static var formatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return formatter
    }()
    
    static func decode(_ value: String) throws -> Date {
        formatter.date(from: value) ?? Date()
    }
    
    static func encode(_ date: Date) -> String {
        formatter.string(from: date)
    }
}
```

Then use it like

```swift
struct ExampleDateFormatProblem: Codable {
  @DateFormatted<DayDateStrategy> var startDate: Date
  var createdAt: Date

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case startDate = "start_date"
    case createdAt = "created_at"
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Your date formatter is wrong. It might fail in many cases. Btw setting the current date is even worst than failing.

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes that is true but it's a start, I wanted to type something out quick I can add a Error enum later. *and no I didn't vote my own answer*

Comment: @LeoDabus why is the date formatter wrong? And yeah, it might be preferential in your own project to fail rather than to set the current date but unless you know the specific requirements of this particular project then you can’t comment on that.

Comment: I know you didn't. FYI if a date string has no time and you don't set the date formatter calendar it will fail with daylight savings transition dates where there is no midnight

Comment: @thecoolwinter Also you should always set your date formatter's locale to en_US_POSIX when using a fixed date format

Comment: One more issue there is if you don't set a calendar it might interpret the date using the device's calendar. If the device calendar is set to buddhist it will result in a date more than 500 years ago

Comment: @Fogmeister I am making a favor voting this down and telling OP what's wrong with his answer

Comment: @LeoDabus why not just write an answer. You seem to have a lot to say about this topic. Write an answer and then you could earn the rewards from it also. 

Comment: @thecoolwinter And don't escape the Z in your date formatter. It is there to interprete the timezone that comes in your date string. If you ignore it it will decode using the current timezone. FYI `Z` in the end of a date string means it is UTC time. `Z` in your date formatter means it is expecting timezone info in this format `-0800`. Note also that date formatter is a little lenient and Z does work to interpret Z as well in the date string but you should use capital X (X, XX, XXX, XXXX, XXXXX or ZZZZZ) in your date format. `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"`